# How to replace the Chevron icon of accordion in bootstrap by your own choice of image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function toggleChevron(e) {
            $(e.target)
                    .prev('.panel-heading')
                    .find("img.indicator")
                    .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down');
        }
        $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
        $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
    });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table borderless">
                <tr><td>Nature of Job</td><td>:</td><td>Provide health advice at a fast-paced call centre</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Location</td><td>:</td><td>Pune, Jaipur or Guwahati</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Qualifications</td><td>:</td><td>B.Sc. (Nursing, Pharmacy) or BAMS or Diploma in Pharmacy</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Experience</td><td>:</td><td>0 – 2 yrs, retired nurses may apply</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Required skills</td><td>:</td><td>Advanced competence in writing, reading and speaking English,Hindi and regional language</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Desired skills</td><td>:</td><td>Computer proficiency</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my code so I want my own image as an arrow mark that should toggle so how to replace that in js?
I have both up arrow and down arrow image but finding it difficult to place or toggle in js.

Comment: Do you have your own CSS file? If so, you can add a class e.g. .my-own-image-up { url: myimage-up} and .my-own-image-down{url: myimage-down} Add that css class to your js file. Now replace glyphicon-chevron-up and glyphicon-chevron-down with your own class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this css will help you..

```
.panel-title a.accordion-toggle
   {display: block;
   background: url("your image path") no-repeat center right;}
.panel-title a.accordion-toggle.collapsed
   {color: inherit;
   display: block;
   background: url("your image path") no-repeat center right;}
```